# Scala groupBy: Want array indices satisfying predicate, not array values

Tags: scala, group-by

```
    val m = Array(10,20,30,30,50,60,70,80) groupBy ( s => s %30 == 0)
    m(true).map { kv => println(kv) }
```

prints the values 30, 30, 60

I want the indices i.e. 2, 3, 5 to be printed.

How do I go about this?

Comment: BTW, `map { kv => println(kv) }` is pretty weird.  `map` is intended to return a new collection and you're evaluating to `Unit`.  What you really want to do here is `m(true).foreach(println)`

Comment: Thanks. I'm moving from Java to Scala & its taking a while to absorb the functional paradigm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val m = Array(10,20,30,30,50,60,70,80).zipWithIndex.groupBy(s =>
  s._1 % 30 == 0).map(e => e._1 -> (e._2.unzip._2))
```

Just FYI, if you only want the `true` values, then you could go with @missingfaktor's approach and equally you could `partition` this:

```
val m = Array(10, 20, 30, 30, 50, 60, 70, 80).zipWithIndex.partition(s =>
  s._1 % 30 == 0)._1.unzip._2
```

Comment: The reason `zipWithIndex` exists is because what you're trying to do is incredibly common.  It's equivalent to something like `a.zip(0 until a.size)`, but `zipWithIndex` is easier.  If this is the right answer please mark it as so.

Answer (score 6):

```
Array(10, 20, 30, 30, 50, 60, 70, 80)
  .zipWithIndex
  .collect { case (element, index) if element % 30 == 0 => index }
// Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Uh...Nope. Derek had the right solution Your code assumes I know beforehand that (2,3,7) is the solution set of indices for the groupBy...which I obviously don't.

Comment: @missingfaktor Now it's missing the `groupBy` - you should be getting back a `Map` at the end. :)

Comment: @Derek: Why `groupBy` and why `Map`? He is obviously using the wrong HOFs for the wrong purposes.

Comment: @missingfaktor We shouldn't get into a big discussion here, but I think you're assuming he only wants the `true` values and there's no concrete indication of that.  I assumed he wants both `true` and `false`.  My point being that if your assumption's incorrect then it doesn't solve the problem, and if mine's incorrect then you could certainly argue I've written too much "stuff".

Comment: @Derek: Sure, we are solving two different problems here. Maybe OP should have been clearer in his wording of the question.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way to do it:

```
Array(10,20,30,30,50,60,70,80).zipWithIndex.filter{ _._1 % 30 == 0 }.map{ _._2 }
```

I find the `.map{ _._2 }` easier to comprehend than `.unzip._2`, but maybe that's just me. What's also interesting is that the above returns:

```
Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 5)
```

While the unzip variant returns this:

```
scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 5)
```

Comment: `collect` is just a combination of `filter` and `map`, though in this case it makes you type slightly more. :-)

Comment: I like the `collect` solution too, because it explicitly names element and index instead of using the slightly ugly _1 and _2.

Comment: except that this one is more amenable to single lines.. which is sometimes desirable

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more direct way,

```
val m = Array(10,20,30,30,50,60,70,80).zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 % 30 == 0).unzip
```

obtains the values and indices as a pair, `(ArrayBuffer(30, 30, 60),ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 5))` You can print just the indices with

```
m._2.foreach(println _)
```

Comment: Yeah this one works too...I really want the indices and not the values, so I'll stick with Derek's _._2 which does the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
val a=Array(10,20,30,30,50,60,70,80)
println( a.indices.filter( a(_)%30==0 ) )
```